# Use refrence of variable in another class

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner in my activity that contain list of Opeartor I want to put that list in other class and call its reference in spinner adapter .how can I do that

here is the list of Operator

```
public class COperatorData {
protected COperatorStorage item[];

public void operator(){
    item = new COperatorStorage[5];
    item[0] = new COperatorStorage("Select Operator", null);
    item[1] = new COperatorStorage("Aircel", "AIRCEL");
    item[2] = new COperatorStorage("BSNL", "BSNL");
    item[3] = new COperatorStorage("Idea", "IDEAS");
    item[4] = new COperatorStorage("Vodafone", "VODAS");

}
```

}
here is COperatorStorage:-

```
public class COperatorStorage {
public String name;
public String code;

public COperatorStorage(String name ,String code){
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String getCode(){
    return code;
}
public String toString(){
    return name;
}
```

}

and here is spinner in my activity

```
ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, item);
    m_OperatorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_OperatorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            COperatorStorage operatorName = item[position];
            String selectedOperatorCode = operatorName.code;
            Log.e(TAG, "Operator code:-" + selectedOperatorCode);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

here item is the reference which I want to call in spinner adapter.

Comment: Please show the full class definitions of both places where you want to reference the variable. Generally, making the list publicly static would work, but there should be another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps :

**First Declare one common class, you can give any name as per your suitable**

I am giving it name as "CommonClass.java"

**CommonClass.java**

```
  public class CommonClass
   {
      public static final COperatorStorage item[] = {new COperatorStorage("Select Operator", null), new COperatorStorage("Aircel", "AIRCEL"), new COperatorStorage("BSNL", "BSNL"), new COperatorStorage("Idea", "IDEAS"), new COperatorStorage("Vodafone", "VODAS") };
   }
```

Now, use this anywhere like below whenever you want,

**MainActivity.java**

```
    ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, CommonClass.item);

    m_OperatorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: public static final COperatorStorage item[] =

Comment: import this COperatorStorage class in CommonClass,

And 

Also remove new line enter as above

Answer (score 1):

You can make an arraylist public static as below in any one class:

```
public class CommonUtils{
     public static ArrayList<COperatorStorage> listItems=new ArrayList<COperatorStorage>();

}
```

Add data to this list in whichever class you like as below:

```
 .........
 .........
 CommonUtils.listItems.add(new COperatorStorage("Select Operator", null));
 CommonUtils.listItems.add(new COperatorStorage("Aircel", "AIRCEL"));
 CommonUtils.listItems.add(new COperatorStorage("BSNL", "BSNL"));
 .........
 .........
```

And you can make the adapter in the class you want to show the spinnerand fill the global arraylist as below:

```
  ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, CommonUtils.listItems);

m_OperatorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an instance of the `COperatorData` and probably change the method  `public void operator(){` to a constructor, `public COperatorData(){`

Then implement a `public COperatorStorage[] getItems()` method, and use it for the adapter.

```
COperatorData data = new COperatorData();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<COperatorStorage>(getActivity(), R.layout.recharge_item, data.getItems());
```

Comment: I'm not going to provide working code for something that you should understand and learn the general concepts of, sorry.